# Changing the pagefile.sys location on virtual servers

Tags: vmware, windows-server-2003

We currently run 3 physical servers on VMWare 4.0 that manage around 13 virtual servers. The virtual servers have varying numbers of cores and memory in addition to being connected to a SAN. In general, we run minimum 2 cores and 4 GB RAM. Is there any advantage, given that our servers are virtual and attached to a SAN, of moving the pagefile.sys file to a drive on a server other than the C: drive? Someone has suggested moving the pagefile.sys file to a small 8GB to 10GB drive. I aleady have the pagefile.sys file set as an exception to our antivirus so that it is not scanned. So I do not see how moving it to another drive will help, especially since we are virtual.

Answer (score 2):

If you are replicating SAN storage accross two sites its definately worth seperating them onto a seperate datastore. That way you can replicate/mirror only the required datastore and reduce the amount of redundant data that is being passed between the sites.

Answer (score 1):

If the pagefile would still be on the same spindles there wouldn't be any reason to move it to a new drive. The only reason you would want to move the pagefile is if you are using it often due to ram restrictions and if the move would get the read/writes off to new spindles. There was an article I read about this but I can't find it to link it but when you think about the reasons to move it make sense.